# lwjgl throws errors when added to an android project

Tags: java, android, gradle, opengl-es, lwjgl

I have spent the past week working on trying to get lwjgl to work in eclipse for an android project but whenever I add the jars I get an error saying Dx unsupported class file version 53.0

I have googled this but all i can find is the error for 52.0. i do know that android projects already support opengl es but i want to build a library to use as a cross platform engine that will check if its an android project or a desktop project so i want to be able to use opengl es on desktop as well.

i have tried using gradle to set it up as well and i cant figure it out because that keeps throwing errors too saying it cant find the lwjgl dependencies.

i have tried working with the [lwjgl android-test](https://github.com/LWJGL/android-test) and i cant seem to get it to work no matter what i try.

any help as to how i can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.